# How to write a 4 byte unsigned integer to binary

Tags: c++, io

Trying to figure out how to write an unsigned integer to a binary file. As I see it the integer shouldn't take more space then 4 bytes. I have two parts in the below code marked as **Write v.1** and **Write v.2**. The expected behavior would be for both of them to work, but only version 2 does, though it takes up more space then I figure it should.

### Question

<strike>How can I write an unsigned integer to a binary file in 4 bytes? If it's not possible, then please explain why not?</strike>
How can I read and output the unsigned integer in version 1.

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned int x = 4294967295;
  ofstream outfile;
  streampos begin,end;
  ifstream myfile;
  streampos size;
  char * memblock;

  // Write v.1
  outfile.open("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);
  outfile.write((char*)&x, sizeof(unsigned int));
  outfile.close();

  // Output size
  myfile.open ("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
  begin = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  end = myfile.tellg();
  cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";

  // Output content
  size = myfile.tellg();
  memblock = new char[size];
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
  myfile.read (memblock, size);
  myfile.close();

  cout << "content: " << memblock << "\n";

  delete[] memblock;

  myfile.close();

  // Write v.2
  outfile.open("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);
  outfile << x;
  outfile.close();

  // Output size
  myfile.open ("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
  begin = myfile.tellg();
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
  end = myfile.tellg();
  cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";

  // Output content
  size = myfile.tellg();
  memblock = new char[size];
  myfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
  myfile.read (memblock, size);
  myfile.close();

  cout << "content: " << memblock << "\n";

  delete[] memblock;
}
```

#### Output

```
size is: 4 bytes.
content: ����
size is: 10 bytes.
content: 4294967295
```

Comment: How is version 1 not working?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Typo, edited

Comment: @ErikLandvall What typo? The premise of the question is that version 1 doesn't work. However, no problematic symptoms are described.

Comment: @Potatoswatter ooh, nvm. version 1 is not working due to the output seen in the end of the question

Comment: That's exactly what I would expect from binary output interpreted as UTF-8… you should inspect it with a hex editor to see the byte values.

Comment: In the first example you are outputting `memblock` which is a character array. `cout` treats this as a string so the output is exactly what one would expect. It is also has undefined behavior written all over it since the string may be unterminated and `cout <<` may access an element outside the bounds of `memblock`

Comment: Ok, so the question should be, how do I read and output an unsigned integer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1. - You write as binary - read in array - print as string
Problem is at presentation of read data, because raw data is presented as null terminated array that is string.

```
unsigned int content;
outfile.read((char*)&content, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Then content is no more array of characters, but serialised int

Comment: I rewrote the question after some input from others in there comments: the new question is: **How can I read and output the unsigned integer in version 1.**

Comment: If I do what you wrote here then I get `invalid pointer` error

Comment: Wait, that error came from me trying to delete a pointer with no address later in the code.. Thank you :D

Comment: @ErikLandvall if you want to just change one line of code you can do `cout << "content: " << *(unsigned int*)memblock << "\n";` instead, which makes it clear that your issue was that while you had the right memory, you were misinterpreting its contents as a string, instead of an unsigned int. It should also, be noted that the binary file you created is not portable across machines with different endianness

Comment: @PeterT Why is it not portable to machines with endianness?

Comment: do you know what endianness is?

Comment: There's a `reinterpret_cast` in there, so you can be almost sure that it is incorrect.  (It's one of those solutions which seem to work, but fail down the road, leaving you with data you cannot read.)

Comment: @LukaRahne I'm familiar with the concept, but I'm still learning this. I understand it has to do with the order of how bytes are arranged to symbolize one or the other type of data. So how could I do this in a correct manner to have it work?

Comment: You should write and read data in predefined endianess and convert to host representation.

Comment: @ErikLandvall it works fine if you run it on the same machine. The issue is, you just dump memory to disk 1-to-1. So if you copy the file from a machine with big endian to a machine with little endian and just read the file byte-for-byte into memory. Suddenly your bytes are swapped.

Comment: @LukaRahne Could you demonstrate how one would do that?

Comment: @PeterT It works fine if read and write on the same machine, with code compiled using the same compiler, the same version of the compiler, and the same compiler options.  In other words, if what you're writing will be read later by the same process, you're safe, or if you can accept loosing it when upgrading to a more recent version of the compiler or the machine.

Comment: @JamesKanze yeah, I might have been unclear. When I say "if you copy the file", I mean the binary file containing the data, not the executable file

Comment: @PeterT That I understood.  But even if you don't copy the file, you can have problems.  Just recompiling your code with a more recent version of the compiler (on the same system) can cause problems, as can recompiling it with different options.  In general, just dumping a bit image of your data to disk is not going to work if you need to be able to read the data some time in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the format of the binary file, then convert
your integer to that.  Typical network format would be
big-endian, so you'd use something like:

```
void
toBuffer( unsigned int value, std::vector<char>& buffer )
{
    buffer.push_back((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
    buffer.push_back((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
    buffer.push_back((value >>  8) & 0xFF);
    buffer.push_back((value      ) & 0xFF);
}
```

with something similar to extract it from the buffer you've
read.  (Obviously, I've neglected a lot of error handling.) You
can use `std::ostream::write` and `std::istream::read` to write
and read the buffer (provided the file has been opened in binary
mode, and is imbued with the "C" locale).

But of course, you might want or need a different binary format.

Comment: This works fine only with compiler for 32bit binary. `unsigned int` should be `uint32_t`

Comment: This works fine for all compilers where `int` is at least 32 bits.  Not all compilers support `uint32_t` (but even those which don't can write a 32 bit integer in binary format).  Making sure that `value` is in the range of a 32 bit unsigned integral type is part of the error handling I mentioned.

Comment: uint32_t is defined in standard libraries <stdint.h> since C99 and <cstdint> since C++11. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer.

Comment: @LukaRahne `uint32_t` is _conditionally_ defined in `<stdint.h>`.  It's not required, and in fact, shouldn't be defined if the underlying hardware doesn't support it directly (and there are still some that don't).

Comment: @LukaRahne So if I use `uint32_t` I have a more portable binary file due to the fact that all compilers doesn't use 32 bit integers?

Comment: @ErikLandvall The type you use internally has no relationship with what's in the binary file (at least if you do it correctly).  If you use `uint32_t`, you have a less portable source file, because it isn't supported everywhere.  (You _might_ want to use `uint_least32_t`.  Or the nature of the software is that it won't work on a machine with less than 32 bits anyway.)

Comment: @JamesKanze The code is serversided and will only be used by me in a docker instance. It will only be compiled by me. But there may be different servers and software that will read the binary file.

Comment: @ErikLandvall If you expect other software to read the data, you must define and document its format.  Or use an existing binary format, like XDR.  Until you've done that, we can't begin to talk about how you will write it.